# JQuery "acitree" plugin. How to check/uncheck all?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, acitree

How to check and uncheck all values from acitree plugin?
http://acoderinsights.ro/en/aciWorker-web-workers-jQuery - this is that plugin
but I can't find method to do something like check all and uncheck all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

helps me:

```
var api = $('#tree').aciTree('api');
var leaves = $("#tree *");
var checkboxes = api.checkboxes(leaves);

checkboxes.each(function (index, item) {
    var $item = $(item);
    api.uncheck($item);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var api = $('#acitree').aciTree('api'),
    leaves = $("#acitree .aciTreeLi .aciTreeLeaf"),
    checked = api.checkboxes(leaves, true);

checked.each(function(index, item) {
   var $item = $(item);
   api.uncheck($item);
});
```